# Loop Through an Table in SQL and Update a row every time

Tags: python, sqlite

and having lots of trouble trying to figure out how I can update several rows in a SQLite data base.

Efectively I am getting an location on a Database I gathered, and running through Google maps to get the Latitude and Longitude. In general its working, but the **loop fails!**

It does it once, gets the first line that meet criteria and finish, and I can´t figure it out why it´s not keep going!! Can anyone help? The script below:

```
# coding=utf-8
import urllib
import sqlite3
import json
conn = sqlite3.connect('ArchDailyProjects.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()

#Google Prep
ServiceUrl="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?"
FimDoURL="&key=????????????????????????????????" #I have the key right, this part works fine

#cur.execute('SELECT * FROM Lugares' )
#print type(cur)
#print cur
#row=cur.fetchone()
for  row in cur.execute('SELECT * FROM LugareS' ):
    print 'Entramos no While'
    Loc_id = str(row[0])
    Loc_Name = str(row[1])
    Loc_Lat = row[2]
    print Loc_Name
    if Loc_Lat is None:
        print Loc_Name
        print Loc_Lat
        print "Buscando "+Loc_Name+" no Google Maps"
        try:
            Url = ServiceUrl + urllib.urlencode({"sensor": "false", "address": Loc_Name}) + FimDoURL
            Uh = urllib.urlopen(Url)
            Dados = Uh.read()
            try: js = json.loads(str(Dados))
            except: js = None
        except: continue
        if "status" not in js or js["status"] != "OK":
            print "===== Beeehhhh!!! Não conseguimos encontrar essa cidade===="
            print Dados
            continue
        else:
            Loc_FormatedAdress = js["results"][0]["formatted_address"]
            Loc_Lat = js["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"]
            Loc_Lon = js["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lng"]
            print Dados
        print 'Endereço Google: ', Loc_FormatedAdress
        print 'Latitude: ', Loc_Lat
        print 'Longitude: ', Loc_Lon
        cur.execute('''UPDATE Lugares SET Latitude= ?, Longitude=?, GoogleLoc=? WHERE id= ? 
        ''', (Loc_Lat, Loc_Lon, Loc_FormatedAdress, Loc_id))
        #row=cur.fetchone()
    else: #row=cur.fetchone()
        continue
conn.commit()
```

Thank you guys!

Comment: Consider segmenting your data retrieval and data update process into two steps and not do both together inside a loop. Getting web api data may conflict with a database batch due to latency, connectivity, etc. Plus maintainability is easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for  row in cur.execute('SELECT * FROM LugareS' ):
    ...
        cur.execute('''UPDATE Lugares SET Latitude= ?, Longitude=?, GoogleLoc=? WHERE id= ?
```

You are executing a different query on the same cursor object; the UPDATE does not have any result rows.

Simply read all the data before looping over it:

```
cur.execute('SELECT id, Name FROM Lugares WHERE Latitude IS NULL')
empty_rows = cur.fetchall()
for row in empty_rows:
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly, and I think I understood, the concept of the problem!

Answer (score 8):

If the file is large, you may not want to load the entire database into memory with "fetchall" but read only one row at a time, and update entries on the go. You can do this by creating two cursors.

```
import sqlite3 as sq3
conn = sq3.connect(db_name)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur2 = conn.cursor()

for row in cur.execute('SELECT * FROM Table' ):
    cur2.execute('''UPDATE Table SET variable = ? WHERE id= ?''', (variable, id))
```

works fine.

Comment: Plenty of people said to do this, use two cursors, but you were the one who _showed_ how to do it. Thanks!

Comment: I was doing the same thing, but I'm getting an error:-  OperationalError: database is locked